# How to Shorten Git Bash Prompt (Windows)

Tags: windows, git-bash

How do I shorten my git bash prompt from something like this

```
Malik@LAPTOP-7R9912OI MINGW64 ~/Desktop/test
$
```

to something like this

```
Malik@test$
```

I am using git bash on windows with git version 2.21.0 (26-02-2019)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Git Bash:

```
cd ~
notepad .bashrc
```

In notepad, add the line `PS1="foobar>"` (replace `foobar>` with whatever text you want)

After saving `~/.bashrc`, in Git Bash, run the command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: after the command notepad .bashrc i get a message 'would you like to create a .bashrc file' and it opens a blank file

Comment: @malikbagwala Then say "Yes" to that

Answer (score 35):

An alternative answer is to go to `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile.d` and open the `git-prompt.sh` file. It contains the default configuration/prompt for Git Bash.

```
if test -f /etc/profile.d/git-sdk.sh
then
    TITLEPREFIX=SDK-${MSYSTEM#MINGW}
else
    TITLEPREFIX=$MSYSTEM
fi

if test -f ~/.config/git/git-prompt.sh
then
    . ~/.config/git/git-prompt.sh
else
    PS1='\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\007\]' # set window title
    PS1="$PS1"'\n'                 # new line
    PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[32m\]'       # change to green
    # PS1="$PS1"'\u@\h '             # user@host<space>
    # PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[35m\]'       # change to purple
    # PS1="$PS1"'$MSYSTEM '          # show MSYSTEM
    # PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[33m\]'       # change to brownish yellow
    PS1="$PS1"'\W'                 # current working directory
    if test -z "$WINELOADERNOEXEC"
    then
        GIT_EXEC_PATH="$(git --exec-path 2>/dev/null)"
        COMPLETION_PATH="${GIT_EXEC_PATH%/libexec/git-core}"
        COMPLETION_PATH="${COMPLETION_PATH%/lib/git-core}"
        COMPLETION_PATH="$COMPLETION_PATH/share/git/completion"
        if test -f "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-prompt.sh"
        then
            . "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-completion.bash"
            . "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-prompt.sh"
            PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[36m\]'  # change color to cyan
            PS1="$PS1"'`__git_ps1`'   # bash function
        fi
    fi
    PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[0m\]'        # change color
    # PS1="$PS1"'\n'                 # new line
    PS1="$PS1"' $ '                 # prompt: always $
fi

MSYS2_PS1="$PS1"               # for detection by MSYS2 SDK's bash.basrc

# Evaluate all user-specific Bash completion scripts (if any)
if test -z "$WINELOADERNOEXEC"
then
    for c in "$HOME"/bash_completion.d/*.bash
    do
        # Handle absence of any scripts (or the folder) gracefully
        test ! -f "$c" ||
        . "$c"
    done
fi
```

In my configuration, I commented out the `user@host<space>`, the `MINGW64` and changed the working directory to its basename by changing `\w` to `\W`.

Comment: This works, but be careful: git updates overwrite this file. This file checks for the existence of `~/.config/git/git-prompt.sh` which if exists takes precedence, so you're better of making your changes there, or directly in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: I'm unable to change git-prompt.sh file as the system is complaining that's readonly file. chmod also isn't working (permission denied). What I might be missing?

Comment: Not a good idea to edit this file directly. Just reconfigure `PS1` string in your user file, e.g. `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to offer some tweaks which are based off of [Krizza's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61379148/184546). The prompt file can be overwritten anytime you update your Git For Windows installation so it's best to make a copy of it. Fortunately the file has a built in plan for this:

First make a copy of the default `git-prompt.sh` file and put it in your own personal config location. In my case the command is:

```
cp /c/Program\ Files/Git/etc/profile.d/git-prompt.sh ~/.config/git/
```

**Do not skip this step!** Now make sure to update your copy of the file by removing everything except what's inside of the larger `else` clause where `PS1` is set. (At the time of this writing I'm keeping only lines 12-36.) Note, if you skip this step Git Bash will get stuck in an infinite loop and exit.

Now you can edit your copy of the file however you please. My personal preference is to comment out displaying the user and host, and the MSYSTEM, and instead displaying the current time of day, like this:

```
# PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[32m\]'       # change to green
# PS1="$PS1"'\u@\h '             # user@host<space>
PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[35m\]'       # change to purple
PS1="$PS1"'\D{%H:%M:%S} '      # show current time
# PS1="$PS1"'$MSYSTEM '          # show MSYSTEM
```

I personally find the time of day useful so when I look back at a prompt later I can see the time I ran the preceding command, e.g. `git fetch`, etc.

Comment: for some reason \W didn't work for me I have to use 
PS1="$PS1"'$(pwd)'                 # current working directory
Credit to 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/430411/53125

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just reset PS1 environment variable in .bashrc file.
Like this：

```
export PS1='\[\033[32m\]\u@\[\033[35m\]$MSYSTEM \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1`\[\033[0m\]\n$'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I tried opening Vim text editor in Windows bash and revised the prompt as I have on my Mac.  I could not get the notepad to work as cleanly as using Vim.  I did not want to make any unnecessary config changes.  This method seems straight forward and missing from this thread so I thought I would include what worked for me to change my Bash prompt.

First I opened bashrc file with Vim text editor.

Second I clicked on the letter I on the keyboard to insert text in Vim.

Third I input the desired prompt.

Fourth I wrote (saved) and quit Vim.

Lastly reference the source file of my prompt change.

$ vim .bashrc

In Vim
 - i for Insert
 - PS1="foobar> "
 - Shift + w + q to save command in Vim

To enforce the settings in BASH
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -10):

The:

> LAPTOP-7R9912OI MINGW6

is the name of your PC.

Search in setting

> 'about your PC'

and look for

> rename

There you can rename your pc and it should change the username in git-bash

Comment: While renaming your computer will work to change how a Git Bash prompt appears, it carries with it numerous other side effects, especially if you're on a domain. For that matter, it is not something that can be done if you don't actually own / have Administrator access on the machine you're working on, so this is not a useful answer.

Comment: Computer name is not the only thing they want to change. And "MINGW64" is not part of the computer name.