# Why is git bash for windows slow except when offline?

Tags: git-bash, git-credential-manager

When opening Git bash or running any command, the time it takes to complete these actions is agonizingly long.  The startup time is also way too long. However, if I disable my network connection, it works normally.  Here is what I have tried that didn't work:

- Commenting out "helper = manager" in the config.
- Changing the credential provider from Azure, which it was set to a long time ago, back to https://www.github.com/ in the config.
- Running Bash as an administrator.
- Making sure $HOME points to a local directory.

I saw something about an [AMD issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42888024/git-bash-mintty-is-extremely-slow-on-windows-10-os) and switching to integrated graphics, but I don't have an AMD graphics card and I play games that would be unplayable on integrated graphics.  Given that I have to work with a remote repo for school, disabling my network connection is not an option either.  I also don't want to switch to the windows command shell, and I don't have another device.

I'm not sure how to check [trace logs](https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/issues/424), but I'm willing to try.  I'm running on Windows 10 with bash version 5.2.15(1)-release, and my profile .  Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

First, check what `$HOME` is when opening a bash: any `$HOME` on a network drive is bound to slow Git operation.

Second, activate [`trace2` API](https://git-scm.com/docs/api-trace2) ([Git 2.22+, Q2 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56094711/6309)), especially the perf one:

```bash
$ export GIT_TRACE2_PERF_BRIEF=1
$ export GIT_TRACE2_PERF=~/log.perf
git version
```

You can then see what takes time in a typical Git operation.

As noted in [the discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252920/discussion-between-vonc-and-lee), the same commands executed from a CMD with the [right `%PATH%`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75433297/6309) are working just fine, even with network connected.

```bash
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set "GH=%ProgramFiles%\Git"
set "PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\cmd;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%GH%\mingw64\libexec\git-core;%PATH%"
```

As noted by [Raymond Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75908775/why-is-git-bash-for-windows-slow-except-when-offline/75909346?noredirect=1#comment133891860_75909346), double-check your `.bashrc` and see if a `$PS1` ([`__git_ps1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53784945/6309)) is the culprit: the prompt could take time to be formed after each command execution.
[Shortening said prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75884031/6309) should help.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I checked $HOME already.  I'll add that in.

Comment: @Lee OK, remains the perf log. Check also where your configs are with, in a local repository: `git config --show-origin --show-scope -l`: is there any network path there?

Comment: Program files and home directory are all I see when I run that.  Perf log is sort of hard to interpret, but figures seem to range between 0.06 and 0.14.

Comment: @Lee That seems fast enough. Is this with network pluged in?

Comment: Yes, this is with it plugged in.  I put the logs in a slightly different format and all of the times it reports are very normal.  I should note that if I run a command like pwd, the output comes right away, but there is a delay AFTER the output before I get the cursor back.

Comment: @Lee Mmm, antivirus maybe? Is this only in a Git bash, or do you have the same issue in a CMD [with the `%PATH%` set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75433297/6309) to include Git/Linux commands?

Comment: Added that to the path and it works fine in CMD.  Antivirus doesn't seem to be doing anything strange.  I might try a re-install at this point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252920/discussion-between-vonc-and-lee).

Comment: Maybe it is your prompt that is slow.